# VS Code PHP Installation

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Hello everyone I'm trying run a simple echo " hello " to see if PHP works in VS code and i get the error.

> " 'php' binary could not be either found or executed. Make sure PHP is installed, and add path to "php.executables" setting. "

and here is my settings.json

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default High Contrast",
    "livePreview.notifyOnOpenLooseFile": false,
    "php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe",
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "php.executables": {
    },
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

I have tried adding

```
"C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe"
```

inside the

```
"php.executables": {
    }
```

but i still get the same error.

Comment: It does not tell if you even installed PHP on your computer and the path is correct.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do exactly, but Code does not support running PHP scripts right from the editor. For that, you can use the Code Runner extension. But you still need to install the PHP runtime. What's the extension you're using that provides the `php.executables` directive?

Comment: FYI, I have the "PHP Debug" and "PHP Intellephense" extensions installed for daily work here. The latter requires some additional steps for installation, so just install the former for now. There, I only configure `php.debug.executablePath` when necessary, but generally I just set up `PATH` to include the executable.

Comment: FWIW, `php.executables` is seemingly provided by [DEVSENSE](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DEVSENSE.phptools-vscode) extension. You don't have to set it unless you use that extension and, if you do, you should probably uninstall or disable PHP Intelephense since they both do the same things and they'll probably clash.

Answer (score 0):

i'm better that u have to download the last version of php like **php-8.2.1** then you have to get the path of php **C:\Program Files\php-8.2.1** like this then go to visual studio then ***settings.json*** and do this:

```
"php.executables": {
       "v8.2.1": "C:\\Program Files\\php-8.2.1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to **settings.json** file in Visual Studio Code.
2. Copy this code into your json file:

```
"php.executables": {
    "v8.1": "C:\\xampp\\php"
 }
```

3. Now save it...

*Please remember that, the **"v8.1"** is the version of the php compiler.*